# Installation from USB fails

Tags: rhel, system-installation, usb-drive

I have a pretty old **Ubuntu 8.04** machine. The machine doesn't have a **DVD reader/writer** in it.

**Challenge**: Now, the challenge I am facing is to install RHEL6 in this machine.

*Obstacle 1*: I needed to make a boot image from **USB disk** so that I can use it to install the **RHEL6** in this machine.

I was able to overcome the *obstacle 1* successfully by following the below approach.

I used the `iso2usb` software and used an existing image of **RHEL6** to have a **bootable USB disk** for installation. It worked perfectly fine in another machine when I tried booting from USB and installing.

*Obstacle 2*: Now, when I use this same **USB** in the server machine, it gives me the first screen where I can select to install the **RHEL6**. After selecting to install the **RHEL6**,  it gives me an error as,

> Unable to find any devices of the type needed for this installation
>   type. Would you like to manually select your driver or use a driver
>   disk?

I am stumped at this obstacle and tried various options to overcome this.

I tried using an **USB** drive with lesser storage (4 GB) since I guessed using larger **USB** storage (earlier I used 16 GB ) sometimes might not work well with the ancient hardware.

I also tried the option specified [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=167991). When the bootloader screen appears,
I added,

```
linux all-generic-ide irqpoll pci=nommconf
```

I also tried using various **USB** ports. The **USB** is getting recognized but again gives the same error as above.

Now the only option left to try is to hook up a **DVD** drive to this machine and try the installation. However, I just want to know if am missing out any other option. Also, is it possible that the installation is failing because of the hardware in the machine? I am not sure if the driver update for the **USB** drives might fix the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the necessary USB drivers are not available for this HW. If you can find a USB thumbdrive that works on this system you can do a remote install like so: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Performing_a_CentOS_6_Network_Installation

Comment: @slm, thanks. If I do network installation, I am not sure if the network drivers are available to carry on the RHEL6 installation.  I mean, the error is because, for RHEL6 to be installed we need some newer drivers right? I doubt if the newer drivers for Network cards are available in that older Ubuntu machine.

Comment: If you use a network image of RHEL/CentOS you can typically put that onto a USB drive and then boot using it. They typically have vanilla drivers which I've had good success with in the past.

Comment: You can also always pull the HDD out of the system and do the install on another system, and then put the HDD back into the problem system.

Comment: @slm, I wish I thought of it yesterday itself. Anyways, I learnt how to do the installation from USB stick and what all possible issues I could run into if I try from USB stick. :)

Comment: You can also sometimes use the Fedora .img images to bootstrap a system, and then point it at a CentOS iso via HTTP server for the actual image to do the install. Noticing that I've run into this problem before yet? 8-)

Comment: If the system supports PXE booting you can also put an image on a tftp server and boot it off of that too. http://www.howtogeek.com/57601/what-is-network-booting-pxe-and-how-can-you-use-it/